# How to publish a composer package with bundled assets included using Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: package, composer-php, gitlab-ci

I have a composer project that contains some assets (javascript, css). These assets are bundled in my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. At a later stage in the pipeline, a composer package gets created. This composer package, however, does not contain the bundled assets. Is there a way to include these bundled assets into the composer package without having to commit them to the repository itself?